# .NET - use Reflection to populate object

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

Please see the code below:

```
Public MustInherit Class clsType
        'Public Overridable Sub PopulateDataTable(ByVal columns As DataColumnCollection, ByRef objType As clsType, ByVal row As DataRow)
        Public Overridable Sub PopulateDataTable(ByVal columns As DataColumnCollection, ByVal row As DataRow)
            For Each column As DataColumn In columns
                Dim ColumnName As String = column.ColumnName
                Dim type As Type = Me.GetType
                Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = type.GetProperties()
                For Each PropertyInfo In properties
                    If PropertyInfo.Name = ColumnName Then
                        'Dim ColumnValue As String = row(ColumnName)
                        Dim PropertyInfo2 As PropertyInfo = Me.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyInfo.Name)
                        'PropertyInfo2.SetValue(Me, Convert.ChangeType(ColumnValue, PropertyInfo2.PropertyType), Nothing)
                        PropertyInfo2.SetValue(Me, Convert.ChangeType(row(ColumnName), PropertyInfo2.PropertyType), Nothing)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End Sub

        Public Overridable Sub PopulateDataReader(ByVal objDR As DbDataReader)
            objDR.Read()
            For value As Integer = 0 To objDR.FieldCount - 1
                Dim ColumnName As String = objDR.GetName(value)
                Dim type As Type = Me.GetType
                Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = type.GetProperties()
                For Each PropertyInfo In properties
                    If PropertyInfo.Name = ColumnName Then
                        'Ship ship = new Ship();
                        'Dim ColumnValue As String = objDR.GetValue(value)
                        If IsDBNull(objDR.GetValue(value)) = False Then
                            Dim PropertyInfo2 As PropertyInfo = Me.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyInfo.Name)
                            PropertyInfo2.SetValue(Me, Convert.ChangeType(objDR.GetValue(value), PropertyInfo2.PropertyType), Nothing)
                        End If
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End Sub

    End Class

Public class TestType
    Inherits clsType
 Private _TestAttribute1 As Integer
 Private _TestAttribute2 As Integer

 Public Property TestAttribute1() As Integer
      Get
        Return _TestAttribute1
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _TestAttribute1 = value
      End Set
 End Property

Public Property TestAttribute2() As Integer
      Get
        Return _TestAttribute2
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _TestAttribute2 = value
      End Set
 End Property
End Class
```

I am able to do something like this in the code that uses the Data Transfer Object:

```
dim objTestType As new clsTestType
objTestType.PopulateDataReader(objDR)
```

objDR is a .NET Data Reader.  The columns in the database match the property names in the class.  Once the statement above has run, then the object (objTestType) is populated with values.

I have never seen this done before.  Is this bad practice in terms of arhitecture(design) and performance? i.e. using Reflection to populate an object from a DataReader/DataTable?

Comment: Dude, don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use an ORM.

Comment: The app contains a lot of ADO.NET code.  I want to move to an ORM in the future, but I am planning to use this approach for the time being.

Comment: reflection will be very slow. you'll need to optimize that away.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by: "you'll need to optimize that away".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflection in this manner is one of the possibilities when you want to produce an ORM. There are pros and cons, but it's not a bad idea per se.

What *is* bad with this code is the performance, because this is literally the slowest possible way to transfer the data. This shouldn't be surprising, as reflection is inherently slow and this is a "naive" straightforward implementation without any frills at all.

It's certainly possible to base the ORM code on reflection, but if performance is a consideration you will need to do much better than this. An example of what I 'm talking about is using [`Reflection.Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) to create dynamic assemblies at runtime based on the information coming in from reflection; this will improve the performance to the neighborhood of strongly-typed code.

However, doing this and doing it correctly will be a lot of work. So if performance matters and straight reflection won't cut it, consider using an established library such as [Emit Mapper](http://emitmapper.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks +1.  How much slower is it likely to be? I realize it may be difficult to predict.  Is it two times slower or a hundred times slower?

Comment: OK thanks.  I was thinking about having a function in each DTO called executeDataReader, then I could map the fields manually.  What do you think of this idea? I think it may go against what DTOs should be used for but I am not sure.